# Custom event in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am binding custom event on buttons to apply Jquery ui button plugin like :

```
      $(document).ready(function() { 
        $(".uibutton").live("CustomEvent", function() { $(this).button(); });
        $(".uibutton").trigger("CustomEvent");
      });

      <input type="button" class="uibutton" >
```

Now this works good for the button which are `present in the MarkUP` but the buttons which are `created dynamically` with `class uibutton`, this is not working. Can anybody please tell me why ?

Comment: What version of jQuery are you using? `live` supported custom events since 1.4. If you're using a later version, you should be using `on` or `delegate` though, since `live` is deprecated.

Comment: Are you triggering the event after you add the new buttons?

Comment: You've got an error in your code, close the quote mark at `$(".uibutton)`

Comment: The errors comes when i was writing my question and by the way i tried `on` also and its still not working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$(".uibutton).trigger("CustomEvent");

There is missing closure quotation.

it should be like this:

$(".uibutton").trigger("CustomEvent");

try it.

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned in the comments, the problem seems to be that even though the custom event is successfully bound even for dynamically created buttons with class uibutton, the event will still need to be triggered again every time a new button has been created. The .trigger() in your .ready() function will only affect the buttons existing at that point in time.

Answer (score 1):

I know that you have mentioned using `on()` and it didn't turn out to be working, but please make sure you have used it like this:

```
$(document).on("click", ".uibutton", function() {
  /// My code....
});
```

And test it again.

The thing is, you need to add this handler to `document` element, which might not be obvious from documentation. Only that way you will be able to use `on()` just like `live()`. And please do use `on()` version, since latter will be removed from jQuery at one point or another.